# I can't exit my local network

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I have a Wimax Router for my internet access (192.168.15.1 on local) connected to micro hub.
I have a ARM Archlinux odroid machine (192.168.15.2) connected to same Hub.
I have Ubuntu PC (192.168.15.10) connected to same Hub.

OK for access from PC to internet.
OK for access from PC to odroid with ssh because it has no screen.
OK for ping 192.168.15.1 and 192.168.15.10 from odroid.

But on odroid, I can't `ping 8.8.8.8`. I got `Network is unreachable`.

Some idea?

Comment: Do you have a default route?

Comment: ip route show dev WAN got 192.168.15.0/24  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.2

Comment: I put ip route add 0/0 via 192.168.15.1 dev WAN and it's ok. Thanks @Celada

Comment: @Mauricio since you've found what was wrong, 1) edit you post with default route, 2) add an answer with the solution, 3) wait and accept your answer. Comment are not easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I use this command:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.15.1 dev WAN
```

But I don't know how to define a route automatically at network up.

I try uncomment lines but does not work in `/etc/systemd/network/WAN.network`

```
[Match]
Name=WAN

[Network]
DNS=127.0.0.1
Address=192.168.15.2/24
#Gateway=192.168.15.1

#[Route]
#Gateway=192.168.15.1
```

I try to put in `/etc/rc.local` with no success too :(

So I applied this solution:

```
[Unit]
Description=Default Route IPv4
Requires=dnsmasq.service
After=dnsmasq.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip route add default via 192.168.15.1 dev WAN

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In `/etc/systemd/system/default-route.service`